# GDI+ not clearing my window on repaint for vista

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-vista, gdi+

on WM_PAINT i do the following:

```
//RectF mNameRect;
//WCHAR* mName;
//HWND mWin; // this is the window handle
{
PAINTSTRUCT ps;

HDC hdc = BeginPaint(mWin, &ps);
Graphics g(hdc);
g.Clear(Color::White);

StringFormat stringForm;
stringForm.SetLineAlignment(StringAlignmentCenter);
stringForm.SetAlignment(StringAlignmentCenter);

// set the rectangle to the size of the whole window

mNameRect.Width = static_cast<float>(size.cx);
mNameRect.Height = static_cast<float>(size.cy);

g.DrawString(mName, -1, &mNameFont, mNameRect, &stringForm, &mNameBrush);

EndPaint(mWin, &ps);
}
```

In XP this works fine, the mName is displayed in the middle of the window. However on Vista the text doesn't move, it stays in its location no matter how I resize the window. the `g.Clear(Color::White)` doesn't seem to do any difference. The text doesn't even change position when the window is hidden behind another window and on focus needs to be repainted again.

How do I make mName change position in Vista?

**Edit:**
The paint code gets called via WM_PAINT and via WM_SIZE in the following manner:

```
// WndProc function
switch (msg){
    case WM_SIZE:
    // intentionally call paint when WM_SIZE is triggered
    case WM_PAINT:
        paint();
    break;
```

Comment: Did you check that `size` changes value on Vista?

Comment: @Thomas: I added the code that calls paint. The size is collected via GetWindowRect() at the beginning of paint(). So Yes - the size does change.. :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are explicitly calling your `paint()` function when the window is resized. However, your window is not invalidated, so it could be that the system is restricting your painting efforts to the region marked "dirty".

Instead of calling `paint()` directly, it is better to use [`InvalidateRgn`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145003%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to trigger a repaint. This will cause a `WM_PAINT` to be sent which will be handled by your application in the normal way. As a bonus, you can also tell `InvalidateRgn` to erase the background for you

```
InvalidateRgn(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);
```

Comment: Awesome, you solved two of my headscratching issues in a matter of minutes. Thanks!

Comment: BTW, do you know the reason why it works for XP but not for Vista?

Comment: Apparently, Vista does more aggressive optimizing to minimize the amount of painting. I'm actually surprised that it did work on XP.